# script relationship in javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have this pretty simple script relationship: 
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
I'm wondering how could I do the same function that this code does using javascript?

Comment: I want the same code (relation) in a javascript code

Comment: so I want a javascript code that call the source "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"

Comment: Sorry, but you are not very clear. Is what you want to load files via javascript as opposed to loading files with html-tags?

Comment: something like that but not exactly the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Create a `script` tag and append it to the `head` of your html document.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
s.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: it doesn't work..  can you provide me a fiddle?